# Terminating since there is no system app when launching from push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have an application in which the notification arrives when any one answers the question. So when i receive the notification and taps on it i have to take to the answerviewcontroller.
I am using the following code for this. But the application crashes showing "Terminating since there is no system app.". The phone restarts with apple logo. why??? Please help

```
    -(void)pushdetailsViewController
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
         QPYourQuestionController *controller = (QPYourQuestionController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"yourQuestion"];
      [[QPCommonClass initializeUserDefaults]setObject:[pushDictonary valueForKey:@"question_id"] forKey:@"currentquestionID"];
        NSLog(@"Dictionary %@",pushDictonary);

        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];


    });
}
```

Comment: Why you use `dispatch_async ` block? try delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't answer your questions but might help people with the same issue. This is Apple bugs you can show [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20240), Nobody can figure out the exact solution for that.

**Solution 1:**
 You're confusing `SpringBoard` and `storyboards`. Your `storyboard` is fine but you need to reboot your device (or Quit and restart the Simulator), as the `SpringBoard` (the process which handles the home screen) has died.

**Solution 2:** Please remove `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` statement and uninstall app & clean & build

**Solution 3:** That error message is just telling you that `iOS` stopped running. So obviously the app is no longer running and won't be able to again until the iPad finishes rebooting. As far as what causes the crash you need to do some more exploring. Definitely turn on exception breakpoints to see if you can catch the crash before the whole device `crashes`. Another thing to keep in mind is that the debugger, for whatever reason, will not work if you have distribution profiles installed. If you have an app with an included push profile, for example, it will always crash shortly after launch because the debugger takes it down with it.

**Solution 4:** What it worked for me was to delete the app in the iPhone simulator, force quit the simulator and hit run again in `Xcode`.